# I get 6 as State result for a blank CD

Tags: c#, imapi

I don't know why I get 6 as a result when I insert a blank media in my burner. To my understanding there is no 6 in the states of the enumeration of `IMAPI_FORMAT2_DATA_MEDIA_STATE`.

Here is a link that contain this states and the example that I am based on : [MSDN:Checking Media Support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364821(v=vs.85).aspx).

```
var state = dataWriter.CurrentMediaStatus;                        
Debug.WriteLine((int)state); // outputs 6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a combination of both of them, basically a bitwise operation is calculated on the two (or more values).
When you make an enum with the attribute `Flags` then you can do Bitwise operations on it, even though it should work without the attribute

```
IMAPI_FORMAT2_DATA_MEDIA_STATE_BLANK
IMAPI_FORMAT2_DATA_MEDIA_STATE_APPENDABLE
```

The value of IMAPI_FORMAT2_DATA_MEDIA_STATE_BLANK with an 'OR' operation with IMAPI_FORMAT2_DATA_MEDIA_STATE_APPENDABLE will give 6
in C# it would be value = 2 | 4;

To go further if you want to test if the value contains a certain Option you can go ahead and do something like this

```
if ((value & IMAPI_FORMAT2_DATA_MEDIA_STATE_BLANK) == IMAPI_FORMAT2_DATA_MEDIA_STATE_BLANK)
{
//IMAPI_FORMAT2_DATA_MEDIA_STATE_BLANK is contained
}
```

You can read more about Bitwise operations [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation)

Comment: ok by the way do you know what happens to the system image, would it be automatically deleted or do i have to do it myself, thanks for your help.

Comment: I believe you will need you will need to delete it yourself, I have not test that, I guess you will know when you see it is deleted or not.

Answer (score 4):

It's equivalent to a flaggable enum. 6 is 4 + 2, so the state is both

```
IMAPI_FORMAT2_DATA_MEDIA_STATE_BLANK
IMAPI_FORMAT2_DATA_MEDIA_STATE_APPENDABLE
```